# How to IgnoredPatterns in spring cloud gateway as zuul?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

There are some rest interface which is internal in the next service?

I only found the suggestion how to ignore service in the spring cloud gateway issue. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/185

Anyone has good idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

A long time passed since you asked and there is no good answer yet. I was running in the same issue and I was unable to find nothing better than the suggestion you mentioned.

Just for the record I was able to hide the undesired services using that strategy. In my scenario, I have a Spring Cloud Gateway using Spring Cloud Kubernetes. Therefore the gateway discovers all the K8s services in the same namespace.

First of all I added the label `expose: "true"` to those services to be exposed to the world through the gateway:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: microservice-spring-boot
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    expose: "true"
```

Then I used the label as a condition in the `include-expression` from the locator:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true # Create routes for the discovered services
          include-expression: metadata['expose'] == 'true'
```

Spring Cloud Kubernetes automatically adds values from the K8s service labels to the discovered service metadata. This is configured in this property which defaults to `true`:

```
spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.metadata.labels-prefix
```

The gateway will have routes only for the K8s services matching that label thus exposing only them and hidding any other.